# Nginx: Only use server block if location matches

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a catch all server block like this:

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location /blog{
        # pass request to ghost
    }
    location /{
        # pass request to custom node app
    }
}
```

It passes to the custom node app, which verifies the requested domain, protocol, and path, and issues a single 301 redirect if necessary; we do this to minimize 301 redirects, for SEO purposes.

I also need my ghost blog to only be served at https://www.exmaple.com/blog. I added the following block:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /blog {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

so that requests to the naked domain would get redirected. But now requests to example.com return the default Nginx index.html page. How do I prevent that? I'd like to avoid using `if`.

Comment: So are there two different /blog locations you're redirecting? Why not add the catch all location to your example.com server block?

Comment: I still need all non /blog requests on the naked domain to go to my custom node app. The issue is having a 2nd server block is preventing that from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a catch-all in the naked domain server block that routes to the node application

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /blog {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    location /{
        # pass request to custom node app
    }
}
```

Comment: So just copying the whole `location /` block?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the naked domain only specifies what to do if the location is /blog.  So setting the catchall should get you working.